# how to encrypt/Decrypt .xlsx/.doc files with C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application to Encrtpt/Decrypt files and using [DESCryptoServiceProvider](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010) for this purpose. This seems to work for text files but when I use the same application for .xlsx file, the resulting encrypted file and the decrypted file get corrupted and I'm not able to open that any more. is there any way I can encryt / decrypt different kinds of file like .doc..xls etc.

update : added code for encryption/decryption

```
public static  void EncryptFile(string filepath,string fileOutput, string key)
    {
        FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(fileOutput, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        DESCryptoServiceProvider DESc = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        DESc.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        DESc.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

        ICryptoTransform desEncrypt = DESc.CreateEncryptor();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desEncrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        byte[] byteArrayInput = new byte[fsInput.Length - 1];
        fsInput.Read(byteArrayInput, 0, byteArrayInput.Length);
        cryptoStream.Write(byteArrayInput, 0, byteArrayInput.Length);
        cryptoStream.Close();
        fsInput.Close();
        fsEncrypted.Close();
    }
public static void DecryptFile(string filepath, string fileOutput, string key)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider DESc = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        DESc.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        DESc.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

        FileStream fsread = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        ICryptoTransform desDecrypt = DESc.CreateDecryptor();
        CryptoStream cryptoStreamDcr = new CryptoStream(fsread, desDecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(fileOutput);
        fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptoStreamDcr).ReadToEnd());
        fsDecrypted.Flush();
        fsDecrypted.Close();
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EncryptFile(@"C:\test1.xlsx", @"c:\test2.xlsx", "ABCDEFGH");
        DecryptFile(@"C:\test2.xlsx", @"c:\test3.xlsx", "ABCDEFGH");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not encrypting or decrypting correctly.  Encrypt -> Decrypt will always give a file identical to the input.  If you post your code we may be able to assist in finding the bug in it.

Comment: same code works for .txt file but not for  .xlsx so I'm assuming encruption/decryption is happening correctly but excel needs some thing different.

Comment: Nope you are wrong I'm afraid.  Probably your code only works with some text files and 'appears' to work and not binary files, which would be a bug if the code is supposed to simply encrypt/decrypt files.

Comment: Yes as I suspected: you're using `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter`.  They read and write text files.  Use `FileStream` objects directly instead.  Edit: odd, you're doing it right for Encrypt but using text-mode for Decrypt.  Decrypt needs fixing :)

Comment: thats right. It is working only with text files but but there is nothing specific to txt file added to these function. how to make it work with any "file"?

Comment: Read my comment.  You are using `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` in Decrypt.  StreamWriter/StreamReader are a classes for use with text files.  SO you've written code on purpose that only works with text files.  If you want it to work with other files, don't use `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader`.  You could use `FileStream` like your Encrypt function does, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FileStream`a as suggested in one of the comments by Kieren Johnstone. Also, you're not flushing the streams when encrypting - this may not be done automatically, so you should try and flush the streams, too.